# Confounding variable that is the focus of experiment

Tags: experiment-design, terminology, confounding

The wiki [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) confounding variable as

> an extraneous variable in a statistical model that correlates
>   (directly or inversely) with both the dependent variable and the
>   independent variable

I'm not sure what exactly they mean by "extraneous", but I'm trying to understand whether "confounding" is the right term for variable that is the focus of the experiment.

For example, let's say I want to see if the fraction of criminals staying home (`c`) affects crime rate (`y`). I can't measure it directly, so instead of I regress crime rate on temperature (`x`), in the hope that when the weather is cold, `c` is high. Of course `c` is correlated with both `x` and `y`, but it seems strange to call it "confounding variable". What's the correct term to refer to `c` here?

(Of course, if it turns out that the fraction of *potential victims* staying home is correlated with both `x` and `y`, it would be a standard example of confounding variable.)